# Why does this plot fail when adding scatter but it works when removing it?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following to plot a x date and y decimal. It works great without the commented line (scatter), but if you uncomment it it shows all in one x axis

what am I missing?

thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

fig = plt.figure(facecolor="#979899")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor("#d1d1d1")
plt.grid(True)
plt.title("This is a title",fontsize=16)

plt.xticks([datetime.date(2018,11,20),datetime.date(2018,11,21),datetime.date(2018,11,22)],["11/20","11/21","11/22"])
plt.yticks([0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0],["0.0","0.1","0.2","0.3","0.4","0.5","0.6","0.7","0.8","0.9","1.0"])

x1 = [datetime.date(2018,11,20),datetime.date(2018,11,21),datetime.date(2018,11,22)]
y1 = [0.18,0.32,0.21]

for i,item in enumerate(y1):
    xP = x1[i]
    yP = y1[i]
    plt.text(xP,yP,str(item)+"%",fontsize=11)

#plt.scatter(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the autoscaling of Collections. [This is](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7413) the underlying issue, which is long known, but hard to come by. There are certain cases, where autoscaling does not work reliably, when values are too close to each other. This is unfortunately often the case for dates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x1 = [datetime.date(2018,11,20),datetime.date(2018,11,22)]
y1 = [1,2]

plt.scatter(x1,y1, s=50, color="red")
plt.plot(x1,y1, marker="o", ms=3, zorder=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can however create a `plot` first. This will determine the autoscaling limits sufficiently. After that plot the `scatter`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x1 = [datetime.date(2018,11,20),datetime.date(2018,11,22)]
y1 = [1,2]

plt.plot(x1,y1, marker="o", ms=3)
plt.scatter(x1,y1, s=50, color="red")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: that's a weird bug tks

Answer (score 1):

try setting the limits for both x and y axes:

```
plt.scatter(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.xlim(datetime.date(2018,11,20),datetime.date(2018,11,22))
plt.ylim(0.1,0.4)
plt.show()
```